# C - regexec returns NOMATCH - even though it should?

Tags: c, regex, c99

Regex pattern needs to match the following:

```
abc_xyz_0
abc_1025_01.29.00_xyz_0
abc_0302_42.01.00_xyz_0
```

*(numbers between abc and xyz dont matter)*

So I parse for:

```
(abc_(\w+\.\d+\.\w+)?xyz_0)
```

My code:

```
regex_t r;
unsigned int maxGroups = 3;
regmatch_t groupArray[maxGroups];
char * to_match = "abc_0302_02.01.00_xyz_18 abc_0302_02.01.00_xyz_16 abc_0302_02.01.00_xyz_14 abc_0302_02.01.00_xyz_0 abc_0302_02.01.00_xyz_10 abc_0302_02.01.00_xyz_2"

if (0 != regcomp(&r, "(abc_(\\w+\\.\\d+\\.\\w+)?xyz_0)", REG_EXTENDED)) 
{
    //this does NOT get hit
    printf("regcomp failed")
}
else if(regexec(r, to_match, maxGroups, groupArray, REG_EXTENDED) == 0)
 { *never gets here* }
else
 { printf("regexec returned non-zero(No Matches)\n"); }

regfree(&r);
```

So my guess is either I have the wrong regex (which works fine for my cases defined above - and I used regexpal.com to confirm), or there is something I am missing?

Either way I know I am close and would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: It's as close as this `abc(?:_\d+_\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?_xyz_0`

Comment: @sln I really appreciate the help, but this did not work for me.
With the addition of the "?:", the regcomp fails.
This did not work for me.
(abc_(\?:\\w+\\.\\d+\\.\\w+)?xyz_0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several typos in the code you copied into the question (see below), and you should only pass `REG_EXTENDED` to `regcomp`; the only flags `regexec` recognizes are `REG_NOTBOL` and `REG_NOTEOL`. (See the [`regexec` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regexec.3.html) for details.)

However, the problem is that Posix regex, including the Gnu implementation, does not implement the non-standard escape sequences `\d`. As indicated in the [`regex(7)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html), a pattern can include:

> a '\' followed by one of the characters "^.[$()|*+?{\" (matching that character taken as an ordinary  character),

or

> a '\' followed by any other character (matching that character taken as an ordinary character, as if the '\' had not been present)

Note that the only effect of `\`, in either case, is to cause the following character to be matched as an ordinary character. While the Gnu implementation of `regcomp` does recognize `\w` as a character class, that behaviour is not required by Posix and other implementations might not do so. (It is also not documented, so it may not always work.) And it does not recognize `\d`.

If you are using Posix regexes, you should use Posix standard character classes, so the regex string should be:

```
"(abc_([[:alnum:]_]+\\.[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:alnum:]_]+)?xyz_0)"
```

You'll find a list of Posix named character classes in the regex manpage in the previous link (or by typing `man 7 regex` assuming you have installed standard library documentation, which is highly recommended.)

I verified this with your code, after adding the missing semicolon at the end of `char * to_match =...` and changing `r` to `&r` in the call to `regexec`.

Note that surprisingly few online regex resources implement the Posix regex specification; http://regexpal.com, for example, only provides the options of PCRE- and Javascript-style regexes.

---

Each time you call `regexec`, you get the first match in the string you pass to it, according to a fixed algorithm described in [`man 7 regex`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html):

> In the event that an RE could match more than one substring of a
>          given string, the RE matches the one starting earliest in the string.
>          If the RE could match more than one substring starting at that point,
>          it matches the longest.  Subexpressions also match the longest
>          possible substrings, subject to the constraint that the whole match
>          be as long as possible, with subexpressions starting earlier in the
>          RE taking priority over ones starting later.  Note that higher-level
>          subexpressions thus take priority over their lower-level component
>          subexpressions.

If you want to find multiple instances of a pattern in the same string, you need to call `regexec` in a loop. Each time through the loop, you give it the address of the first unmatched byte from the previous match (i.e. `string + matches[0].rm_eo`) until it reports no more matches. If you rely on `^` anchors in your match, you will need to pass the correct value of the `REG_NOTBOL` flag to each call to `regexec`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance. Followup question: If I want a non-capture group, how would I go about that? After I execute "regexec()", I only want one capture group, and not multiple. The reason being is if I have multiple instances of abc_####_##.##.##_xyz_0, I want to provide options for the user.
Is the only way around this is by doing:
abc_xyz_0|abc_[[:alnum:]_]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:alnum:]_]+xyz_0
The noncapture group ?: is not recognized, and I am not seeing anything in the man pages.

Comment: Executing with your suggested regex string, (with only one match in the buffer), I get both "abc_####_##.##.##_xyz_0" AND "####_##.##.##_".
Receiving 2+ groups is fine, but only if there are 2+ matches in the buffer.

Also apologies for the syntax errors, the regex/buffer was a lot more complicated than in the question, so I tried to simplify the code down by removing function calls and such, so that the average reader can understand.

Comment: @GraysonHenry: Each time you call `regexec`, it will return exactly one match, filling in the captures for that match. That's the way (most) regex libraries work. You provide multiple match groups because you want multiple captures *from the same match*. Posix regex does not support the `(?:...)` syntax to not capture a group, partly because capturing is quite cheap. Just ignore the captures you don't care about. You are not obliged to provide a match array with room for all the captures in the regex, as long as you tell `regexec` how many groups you want to capture.

Comment: The buff that I am parsing for is generated, thus I am not sure how many matches I expect. If more than one match is found, I capture each match, and then I suggest to the user which of the matches they wish to use. I can relay every other match to avoid the duplicates, but that just seems like extra logic. I was just wondering if there was another way to capture just 1 match, if there is only 1 match in the buffer. For what I am trying to do, is there anything wrong with my suggested regex, or is there a simpler way: "abc_xyz_0|abc_[[:alnum:]_]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:alnum:]_]+xyz_‌​0" ?

Comment: @GraysonHenry: I'm obviously not explaining well. Let me try again. Every time you call `regexec` you get *exactly one match*, if there is one. Since regexec stops as soon as it finds a match, it will never see the second match, if there happens to be one. Regexec searches for the first match, and that is what you get. A match consists of a fixed number of capture groups, one for the match as a whole, and the remaining ones corresponding to each parenthesized expression in the regex. You get a submatch entry for each capture, but they all belong to the same match.

Comment: .. And you always know exactly how many capture groups to expect. All you need to do is count the open parentheses in your regex.

Comment: thanks for all the help. I created a while loop around regexec to return to me all the matches of the buffer. I also only looked for one capture group so I do not run into that problem I listed above. Apologies for the confusion, this helped immensely.